# IOC principle - Servlet container implementation

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection, spring, ioc-containers

[IOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) principle can be implemented, using either:

- Dependency Injection
- Service locator pattern

This [article](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) also supports these two approaches for implementing IOC principle.

---

Spring IOC container is named after IOC principle that supports IOC implementation using *Dependency injection*, where implementations(`<bean/>`) can be injected at runtime as constructor-based or setter-based.

---

My understanding is, Servlet container(Ex: Apache tomcat) in it's implementation follow IOC principle because in runtime, servlet configuration information(from `web.xml`) is injected(more in next para) to pick corresponding servlet class implementation based on the configured data given in `web.xml`.

Following URL pattern matching rules, Servlet container takes configuration information of `MySeervlet` from `web.xml` and injects into `GenericServlet::init(ServletConfig)` method. Injects servlet configuration but not servlet implementation.

`GenericServlet::init(ServletConfig)`->`GenericServlet::init()`-‌​‌​>`GenericServlet::s‌​er‌​vice()`->`HTTPServ‌​let:‌​:service()`->`My‌​Servle‌​t::doGet()`

---

The purpose of both containers differ. But,

Does servlet container use service locator pattern  to  implement IOC principle?

Answer (score 0):

Servlet containers provide a [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) that can be interpreted as an implementation of the *service locator pattern*.

In this case your application is loosely coupled to services locked up in the container. The implementation of the services returned by the container can be changed by reconfiguring the container without touching the application.

Comment: you mean reconfiguring using `web.xml`?

Comment: `web.xml` is part of your application and is packaged with `app.war`. If we change it we change the application. Service implementations are either supplied through platform extensions (`<JRE_HOME>/lib/ext`) or are supplied to the `ext` path given by system property `java.ext.dirs`. See the e.g. [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html) for details.